# How to Query Select all children of a class, but no grandsons of that class

Tags: css, queryselector

I have the css class 'control', and I want to get all the 'control' children elements from my container, but I dont want to get grandsons 'control'.

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <div id='div1' class='control'>
        <div id='div2' class='control'></div>
        <div id='div3' class='control'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='other'>
        <div id='div4' class='control'></div>
        <div id='div5' class='control'>
            <div id='div6' class='control'></div>
            <div id='div7' class='control'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The call below will get me all the controls inside 'mydiv'.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv .control');
```

I want a query that brings me only #div1, #div4 and #div5;
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only `querySelector*` it will not work at the moment.
In the future, browsers will support the `:has()` pseudo-selector.

Then you can select only elements which has or not has elements inside them like this:

`#mydiv .control:not(:has(.control))`

See the current browser support for this: https://caniuse.com/css-has

---

For now you need following sulution:

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv .control')].filter(element => {
   return element.parentNode.closest('.control') == null
});

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div id='mydiv'>
    <div id='div1' class='control'>
        <div id='div2' class='control'></div>
        <div id='div3' class='control'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='other'>
        <div id='div4' class='control'></div>
        <div id='div5' class='control'>
            <div id='div6' class='control'></div>
            <div id='div7' class='control'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

Get at first all `.control` elements into an array (`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` and `NodeList` does'nt have methods like `filter`. So we extract it with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `[...variable]`

Then filter all elements which has no parent elements named `.control`.
`.closest()` can return itself, so we need to make sure we call `parentNode` at first.

---

**UPDATE End September 2022**

Browser are starting to implement `:has()`

Comment: Thank you verymuch. The only thing I didnt explained is that 'mydiv' could be inside another 'control' upper on the document tree, thus I need to make a few changes in your solution. But I get it: I need to make it trhough JS.